# Stored procedure handling multiple SQL statements in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm creating a stored procedure in Snowflake that will eventually be called by a task.

However I'm getting the following error:

> Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead

And not sure how approach the advised solution within my Javascript implementation.

Here's what I have

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myStoreProcName()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
$$
var rs = snowflake.execute( { sqlText: 
`set curr_date = '2015-01-01'; 


CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE myTableName AS 


with cte1 as (
SELECT
  * 
FROM Table1
where date = $curr_date
)
,cte2 as (
SELECT
  * 
FROM Table2
where date = $curr_date
)

select * from
cte1 as 1 
inner join cte2 as 2
on(1.key = 2.key)

`
  
   } );
return 'Done.';
$$;
```

Comment: You need one statement like "rs = snowflake.execute..." per sql statement. You can have as many of these statements as you want within the SP

Comment: will that capture the variable that i set though and propagate it to the other query?

Comment: Everything between the 2 $$ needs to be a valid set of javascript statements - you can't just write SQL statements. I think you probably need to read the documentation as that gives some good examples of how to write SPs

Comment: Thanks @NickW, i didnt see a multi sql query store proc example in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own helper function(idea of user: [waldente](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744096/waldente)):

```
this.executeMany=(s) => s.split(';').map(sqlText => snowflake.createStatement({sqlText}).execute());

executeMany('set curr_date = '2015-01-01'; 
             CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ...');
```

The last statement should not contain `;` it also may fail if there is `;` in one of DDL which was not intended as separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have:

```js
var rs = snowflake.execute( { sqlText: 
`set curr_date = '2015-01-01'; 


CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE myTableName AS 
...
`
```

Instead you need to call `execute` twice (or more). Each for a different query ending in `;`.