# Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead

Tags: stored-procedures, dynamic, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stored procedure in which we pass SQL to execute like

```
set variable;

insert to table 

select from abc;

update abc table;
```

this is returning me below error

> Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead.

there are 3 statements to be executed in sql.execute in stored procedure.

Comment: This question has been answered before, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67184591/stored-procedure-handling-multiple-sql-statements-in-snowflake)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stored procedure handling multiple SQL statements in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67184591/stored-procedure-handling-multiple-sql-statements-in-snowflake)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using new SQL stored procedures you can enclose all dynamic code into [BEGIN … END](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/begin.html#begin-end) blocks, this should allow all code to be executed as one.

You can also try increasing the [MULTI_STATEMENT_COUNT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#multi-statement-count) limit for the session or user on which you are executing this code.

```sql
ALTER USER <UserName> SET MULTI_STATEMENT_COUNT = 0;
```